# Copy all of files to another pc on LAN with Grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

Can i copy all of files from directory to another pc on LAN with Grunt?

For example; I want to copy all of files from my directory to \192.168.1.10\c$\Projects\TestFolder. But how can i do that?

Thanks!

*edit*

i tried with same pc copy settings and i can copy files to another folder on same pc. But when i try copy to another pc, it fails. For example, if you try codes below, it works on same pc; (it copies folder to folder)

```
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: 'app',
        dest: 'dest',
        src: [
          '*.html',
          'views/{,*/}*.html'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But if you try another codes below, it doesnt work; (it tries to copy folder to folder)

```
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: 'app',
        dest: '\\192.168.1.10\c$\Projects\TestFolder',
        src: [
          '*.html',
          'views/{,*/}*.html'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: My brain produces a blue screen when reading this question

Comment: Sorry but why? I'm only asking how to copy files to another pc with grunt plugin?

Comment: 1. Show some effort. You have tried nothing (or didn't provide us with any resources). 2. Do some research on your own. 3. This question is off-topic and just another "give me the codez" question. SO is only for concrete programming issues and not for educating you how to use a javascript library. 4. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry i forgot adding codes. But i searched too much but i didn't find any clue about that.

Comment: Now this looks much better! ;) As I don't know grunt I can only speculate: Have you set permissions correctly on your share (so no authentication is required to write something to that shared folder)?

Comment: I thought same things as you but i dont have permission problem. I can copy-delete-create file on remote folder with windows explorer. I think it will be so stupid question and i can fix some small tricks but for now i didnt find that trick :D

Comment: Do you get a error message or something (check console of your browser)

Comment: Nope. Just continue to work.

Comment: Ah wait, I just saw something. You are using backslash (\\) in your path. You have to escape them (\\\). So your path becomes `dest: '\\\\192.168.1.10\\c$\\Projects\\TestFolder'`

Comment: Oooo it works now! Thanks! If you want, add your comment as answer and i can accept.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question, this would be off-topic on Server Fault too -- please read about what's on-topic there before voting to close under that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript the backslash (\)  is used to escape characters in a string.

Therefor javascript parses them in your path and produces an invalid path. You have to escape the backslashes using (\\):

```
dest: '\\\\192.168.1.10\\c$\\Projects\\TestFolder'
```